# jquery "on" event not firing for click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason I can't get my "on" event to fire for a click event.  Here is what the call and HTML look like:

HTML:

```
<a class="cmt-replies-show" href="javascript:void(0)" id="cmt-count" style="">
  <span>View All</span>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.cmt-replies-show').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  alert("Clicked");

});
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you bind the event after the object is ready in the DOM ?

Comment: @daver I don't know how you tested but you're wrong : it **is** necessary.

Comment: @daver jsbin executes the script only after the dom is ready.

Comment: Your syntax seems okay. The only thing I can think of is what dystroy says: the element is not loaded when your javascript is run (e.g. it isn't in a `$(document).ready( ... );` statement.

Comment: Is there some output in the developer's console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable reason is that the element isn't in the DOM when you bind the event.

If you add the element dynamically, you may do this :

```
$(document.body).on("click", '.cmt-replies-show', function(e) {
```

If your script is included in the page before the element, you may either move your script at the end of the body or call your code on `ready` event :

```
$(function(){
  $('.cmt-replies-show').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Clicked");
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm adding the element dynamically but I though if I called it after the DOM was ready it would pick up any new elements being created...  Your first suggestion worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access element dynamically injected into DOM, you should use the following syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cmt-replies-show', function(e) { 
// your code goes here
});
```

The `document` can be replaced with each parent which is available when document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

What Paul said - make sure you bind the event after the DOM is ready.

FYI if you're directly targeting an element with 'on', you can just use $('a').click(function(){...}); . 'On' is more useful if you want to delegate events like so:

```
$('#container').on('click','a',function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably define the div after the script has executed.

Wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { .... });` to ensure it executes after the full DOM is available.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the reason to be dynamic injection of this link on the page. Your DOM was already in ready state and all the functions were read when this part of code is injected.

When you inject the HTML, bind the element with click function.

Using live() should solve your purpose -

```
 $('#yourLink').live('click', function(){
   //Your logic here
});
```